# How to design an establish a battery topology with a BMS and charge transfer ("active") balancing

Tags: parallel, bms, cell-balancing

I read  several documents about building batteries (e.g., for photovoltaic systems). I still have questions.

1.) LiFePO₄ cells have an internal resistance of a few mΩ. If you connect two such cells with different states of charge in parallel, shouldn't there initially be enormous currents?

If so, how can you create a common state of charge that allows safe parallel connection?

- Option 1: Balance the charging voltage with a suitably sized resistor
- Option 2: Establish same charging voltage by charging/discharging up to a deviation in the millivolt range
- Option 3: Put them in series and implement a balancing circuit

2.) It is recommend to have same "age" SOH of cell connected in parallel. What is the easiest way to determine batteries with same state of health from a given set?

3.) Is the series connection of cells with different SOHs harmless or is there a risk of over-charging when using a charge transfer balancing circuit?

Comment: ... adjusted. thank you

Answer (score 1):

> If you connect two such cells with different states of charge in parallel, shouldn't there initially be enormous currents?

Yes. That why you must never do that.

> how can you create a common state of charge that allows safe parallel connection?

Ideally: Charge each cell with a single-cell charger up to the maximum voltage (3.6 V for LFP Li-ion cells). Then connect the cells in parallel. All the options you listed are not as good, because the Open Circuit Voltage (OCV) of an LFP L-ion cell is very flat over a wide range of SoC levels.

> It is recommend to have same "age" SOH of cell connected in parallel.

That is not a critical requirement. New cells from the same source will have the same SoH. If you're recycling old cells, having the same SoH is the least of your worries.

> What is the easiest way to determine batteries with same state of health from a given set?

Determining the SoH of a Li-ion cell is best done with specialized equipment. The easiest way is to buy a Chinese cell tester.

Without it, you can get a rough idea of the SoH of a cell with two parameters: capacity and series DC resistance. Measure the capacity of the cell by fully charging it, then discharging it through a constant load and integrating the current, until the cell reaches a low voltage cutoff. Measure the resistance of the cell by applying a load and measuring the drop in voltage, divide by the current.

But, again, you're overthinking it.

> Is the series connection of cells with different SOHs harmless

Yes, as long as they are protected by a properly-installed BMS.

> is there a risk of overcharging

No, as long as they are protected by a properly-installed BMS.

> when using a charge transfer balancing circuit?

Charge transfer balancing ('active") is pointless in your case. Forget it. Use plain-old bypass balancing ("passive") instead.

Regardless, this question is moot because the idea of balancing cells in series before connecting them in parallel is a needlessly complicated solution.

Comment: Thank you Davide for accurate answers. Last question actually refers to series. My idea to have e.g. 3 cell in parallel and line these triples up in series, for increased capacity and limited cable work for the balancer.

Comment: "Last question actually refers to series". Start a new submission and ask that question separately. Otherwise, they will remove this question for "lacks focus".